# How to convert date "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss a" into text format?

Tags: swift, nsdate

I am trying to create a function which will convert date into text format like "Just now, 2mins, 1hour, 1day, oct 10". Here is my sample code where I am getting an error at:

```
let components = cal.components([.Day,.Hour,.Minute], fromDate: date, toDate: NSDate(), options:[])
```

Here is my full code:

```
func getTextToDisplayFormattingDate(date: NSDate) -> String {
    var textToDisplay = ""
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss a"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")

    let cal = NSCalendar.current

    let components = cal.components([.Day,.Hour,.Minute], fromDate: date, toDate: NSDate(), options:[])

    switch components.day {
    case 0:
        if components.hour == 0 {
            if components.minute <= 0 {
                textToDisplay = "just now "
            } else {
                textToDisplay = "\(components.minute) min"
            }
        } else {
            textToDisplay = "\(components.hours) hrs"
        }
    case 1...6:
        textToDisplay = "\(components.day) d"
    default:
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd"
        textToDisplay = dateFormatter.string(from: date as Date)
    }

    return textToDisplay
}
```

[image: error]

Comment: Get rid of all of the Swift 2 syntax from your Swift 3 code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it's hard to calculate the **days, hours, minutes** between 2 dates by `NSCalendar.components`, your procedure will cause an unexpected result. Usually, we calculate it by the `TimeInterval` between them. Try this in swift 3.2 or swift 4.0:

```
func getTextToDisplayFormattingDate(date: Date) -> String {
    var textToDisplay = ""

    let now = Date()
    let timeInterval = now.timeIntervalSince(date)
    if timeInterval < 60 {
        textToDisplay = "just now "
    }
    else if timeInterval < 60 * 60 {
        textToDisplay = "\(Int(timeInterval / 60)) min"
    }
    else if timeInterval < 60 * 60 * 24 {
        textToDisplay = "\(Int(timeInterval / 60 / 60)) hrs"
    }
    else {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")

        if timeInterval < 60 * 60 * 24 * 6 { //less than 6 days
            // For getting days
            // textToDisplay = "\(Int(timeInterval / 60 / 60 / 24)) d"

            // For getting weekday name
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"
            textToDisplay = dateFormatter.string(from: date) //weekday name
        }
        else{
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd"
            textToDisplay = dateFormatter.string(from: date as Date)
        }
    }

    return textToDisplay
}
```

And remember use constants to replace expresses like `60 * 60 * 24` to improve performance.

Comment: how can I show weekday name if less than 6 days. ex: just now, hours, Thursday, Wednesday, Tuesday, oct'10, oct'9 @yun chen

Comment: @WhenKey, I updated the answer for getting weekday name if less than 6 days. Try it.

Answer (score 2):

Use like this :

Changes in my code :

1. In place of `NSDate`, I used `Date`.
2. In place of `NSCalendar` I used `Calendar`
3. `components(_:from:to:options:)` has been renamed to `dateComponents(_:from:to:)`
4. `components` values like `day, minute, hour` are `optional`. Thats why i added check before switch.

   ```
   func getTextToDisplayFormattingDate(date: Date) -> String {
       var textToDisplay = ""
       let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
       dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss a"
       dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")

       let cal = Calendar.current
       let components = cal.dateComponents([.day, .hour , .minute], from: date, to: Date())

       if let day = components.day, let minute = components.minute, let hour = components.hour {
           switch day {
           case 0:
               if hour == 0 {
                   if minute <= 0 {
                       textToDisplay = "just now "
                   } else {
                       textToDisplay = "\(minute) min"
                   }
               } else {
                   textToDisplay = "\(hour) hrs"
               }
           case 1...6:
               textToDisplay = "\(day) d"
           default:
               dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd"
               textToDisplay = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
           }
       }
       return textToDisplay
   }
   ```

Comment: You don't need to cast `date as Date`, it's already a `Date`.

Comment: Given the nature of the question, it would probably be helpful if you added a description to your answer that points out all of the fixes you needed to make and why.

Comment: @ViniApp thanks very much !! it really working awesome. appreciated